# nested json object from a single model

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

I have a model class as given below:

```
 public class ApiRequest{
    [JsonProperty(PropertName="name")]
    public string Name{get;set;}
    [JsonProperty(PropertName="description")]
    public string Description{get;set;}
    [JsonProperty(PropertName="privacy.view")]
    public string PrivacyStats {get;set}
}
```

And when I call the API, it should convert this model to a json with nested object for privacy status as below

```
    {
         "name":"Test1",
         "description":"Testing Only",
         "privacy":{
               "view":"unlisted"
}
    }
```

How can I map single model to nested object with out creating another class for the same?

Comment: Did you try using dynamic type for the status ?

Comment: Depending on the JSON serializer you are using (ex: Newtonsoft json) you will have to implement a proper converter. You can check this example for newtonsoft: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm

Comment: It's pretty easier to add additional model for json field `privacy` with one field, than implement custom converter and maintain it.

Answer (score 1):

You should declare one more model for `PropertyStats`. Otherwise, it will be kind of reverse engineering to modify the already created `JSON` string.

Like this:

```cs
public class ApiRequest
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "privacy")]
    public PropertyStats PrivacyStats { get; set; }
}

public class PropertyStats
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "view")]
    public string View { get; set; }
}
```

Then You can serialize it like this.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ApiRequest objApiRequest = new ApiRequest()
    {
        Name = "Test1",
        Description = "Testing Only",
        PrivacyStats = new PropertyStats
        {
            View = "unlisted"
        }
    };

    var serializedString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objApiRequest, Formatting.Indented);

    Console.WriteLine(serializedString);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "name": "Test1",
  "description": "Testing Only",
  "privacy": {
    "view": "unlisted"
  }
}
```

In the future, if you want to add additional property to the privacy model then it will be easy to serialize it.

Like below:

```cs
public class PropertyStats
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "view")]
    public string View { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "status")]
    public int StatusCode { get; set; }
}
```

Serialize like it below:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ApiRequest objApiRequest = new ApiRequest()
    {
        Name = "Test1",
        Description = "Testing Only",
        PrivacyStats = new PropertyStats
        {
            View = "unlisted",
            StatusCode = 1
        }
    };

    var serializedString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objApiRequest, Formatting.Indented);

    Console.WriteLine(serializedString);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "name": "Test1",
  "description": "Testing Only",
  "privacy": {
    "view": "unlisted",
    "status": 1
  }
}
```